# Moving a particular branch from bitbucket repository to Github or Moving Bitbucket repository to Github without commit history

Tags: github, bitbucket

Is there any way we can move a particular branch from bitbucekt repository to Github repository?
Is there any way Bitbucket repository can be moved to Github without moving the commit history(without removing the git folder and re-initializing the git)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple remotes to a repository with `git remote add`. Once a remote exists, you can push whatever you like to it.

In this case, you can push the branch named `newbranch` to a new GitHub-hosted remote by doing something like this:

```
git remote add github https://user@github.com/owner/repo
git push github newbranch
```

This will include all commits associated with that branch, because that's how Git works. (If you just want to give somebody a copy of the code that doesn't include any history, then you should use `git archive` instead.) It will not automatically update the GitHub version with changes made on Bitbucket or vice versa, though you can push updates manually or with a script.